# Params::Validate or Params::Check, why should I prefer the one or the other?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

It is hard for me to choose between two perl modules  - Params::Validate and Params::Check.
I am writing a Mojolicious application which should be easily distributable.
Generally I mean something like uploading a directory structure on a shared hosting and be ready to run.
Params::Validate is quite powerfull and tought, has Pure-Perl implementation.
Params::Check is in the Perl Core distribution since version 5.10.0
Can you point other "why should I prefer the one or the other"?

Comment: I will mention Method::Signatures which now has type/class/role validation, is far less verbose, but has a dependency chain.  http://search.cpan.org/~mschwern/Method-Signatures-20110324.1600_001/lib/Method/Signatures.pm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking through the CPAN bug reports for each of these modules might help you to choose.  Currently, [Params::Check](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Params-Check/) has no bug reports (it only has one wishlist item), but [Params::Validate](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Params-Validate/) has a few.  Check to see if any bug is relevant to your application.

You could also look at the CPAN Testers platform/version matrix to see if there are any fails on platforms that you would be running on.

Comment: Thanks.
I took another approach... at least for now.
Since it is a Mojolicious app and I already use
Mojox::Validator, I decided to try Mojox::Validator for
some of my routines too(not only for form validation).
It has not a common function like "check" or "validate" but I made my own.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Mojo validator probably makes sense.  I just want to point out that the author of `Params::Validate` has shifted towards [Params::ValidationCompiler](https://metacpan.org/pod/Params::ValidationCompiler)

Answer (score 0):

For now you can use **Mojolicious::Validator** for validation parameters in Mojo application. http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Rendering#Form-validation